# Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

i have the following sqlite3 database
[Sqlite Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrUGt.png)

i want to map above tables to python code.
my code is

```
class Attendance(db.Model):
    Id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    day = db.Column(db.Date)
    employee = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, day,employee):
        self.day = day
        self.employee = employee

   def __repr__(self):
       return '<Employee %r>' % self.employee

class AttendanceActions(db.Model):
    Id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    attendance_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Attendance.Id'))
    attendance = db.relationship('Attendance', backref='AttendanceActions', lazy='dynamic')
    action_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    action = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, attendance, action_time, action):
       self.attendance = attendance
       self.action_time = action_time
       self.action = action

    def __repr__(self):
       return '<AttendanceAction %r>' % self.action_time
```

i got error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship AttendanceActions.attendance - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb the error raised from this two lines:  attendance_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Attendance.Id'))
    attendance = db.relationship('Attendance', backref='AttendanceActions', lazy='dynamic')

Comment: The FK reference must be lowercase, because it's referring to the _table_, not the _model_ (Flask SQLAlchemy uses the lower-cased model name as the table name, it appears).  So `db.ForeignKey('attendance.Id')`